# Do I need to manually insert new messages in content://sms/inbox?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

Started learning android for college project recently. I have created an SMS app which is capable of being a default app(minimalistic app though). When I set it to default SMS app, my phone's inbuilt app stopped receiving new messages.

Questions:

1. Do all new messages automatically go in `content://sms/inbox` or do we have to update it manually ? I am asking this because my inbuilt SMS app doesn't reflect the SMS received while it was not default SMS app.
2. Is it necessary to forward new messages to other apps listening for new SMS received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do all new messages automatically go in `content://sms/inbox` or do we have to update it manually ?

No, those messages will not be written to the inbox automatically. The default app is responsible for saving all incoming SMS to the Provider. Though there is no requirement for the default app to do so, if it doesn't save them there, then other apps that query the Provider to read existing messages just won't see them. This would explain why your inbuilt SMS app doesn't see the new messages received while yours is the default.

The only message writes that are handled automatically by the system are for outgoing SMS sent by non-default apps. All other inserts, updates, and deletes are left up to the default app.

---

> Is it necessary to forward new messages to other apps listening for new SMS received?

Not specifically, as it were. Any non-default app that is interested in getting messages as they arrive should be listening for the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast, and the system will send that automatically. Such apps have direct access to the messages, since they're attached to the broadcast `Intent`s as extras.

Beyond that, pretty much the only other (practical) way for non-defaults to read messages, or to be notified of changes, is through the Provider, so as long as you're saving the messages there, such apps are covered, as well.

Comment: So you're saying that  as a default sms app, my app should only manually insert newly received sms in the content://sms/inbox ? I do not need to put the 'sent' sms in the outbox myself ?

Comment: SMS sent by non-default apps using `SmsManager` directly will be saved automatically by the system. Your app is responsible for saving any outgoing messages that it sends itself, including any messages that other apps might send using your app; e.g., by using `startActivity()` with `ACTION_SEND`. Basically, any message that your app touches has to be saved by your app. SMS sent by third-party apps using `SmsManager` directly will never hit your app, though, which is why the system handles those for you.

Comment: @Mike M. I have posted a question about starting the default sms app here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74201835/android-10-api-29-nullifies-users-in-app-request-to-use-default-sms-app  I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas on a solution.

Comment: @AJW Yeah, I saw that earlier, but didn't have anything to suggest or add, really. I would've thought it was something to do with the package visibility restrictions, but those weren't added until 11. Do you know where it's failing, exactly? You might try removing the `if (smsIntent.resolveActivity(this.getPackageManager()) != null)`, since you're catching the possible `Exception` already, and since that's the pattern most are switching to anyway 'cause of the new flaky `PackageManager` behavior.

Comment: I checked the AS Logcat and saw this:  "Unsupported conversation intent action : android.intent.action.SEND".  So I changed the initial new Intent from "...Intent.ACTION_SEND" to "...Intent.ACTION_SENDTO" and all good now!  So mixing SEND first and SENDTO later in the code must have caused a conflict.  I appreciate you for your reply leading me in the right direction and your expertise, cheers.